# Как запустить игру через Port Proton с дискретной видюхой под fedora?

Tags: linux, драйвер, fedora, gpu

Использую ноутбук HP Pavilion g6-2205sr (AMD A8-4500m со встроенной видеокартой HD 7640g + дискретка HD 7670m) с fedora на борту.

Недавно попробовал запустить NFS MW с помощью Port Proton и был разочарован количеством FPS(+-7). Посмотрев лог, оказалось, что ноут всё время работал на встройке. Прописал "lspci | grep VGA"

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
```

"sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:01.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

Как видно, дискретка чиллит без питания. Как заставить её работать?